# Не отображается картинка в админке опенкарта

Tags: php, opencart

[image: сама проблема]

Все проверил, путь к изображению верный, но картинка не открывается, в чем может быть проблема?

```
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_discount_image; ?></td>
          <div class="image">
            <td><img src="<?php echo HTTP_CATALOG.'download/'.$jan;?>"><input type="hidden" name="jan" value="<?php echo $jan; ?>" /> <a id="button-upload-jan" class="button">Обзор</a></td>
          </div>
        </tr>
```

Вот так отображается код в консоли:

```
        <tr>
          <td>Изображение скидки:</td>
          <td><img src="http://localhost/ocstore/download/youtube-40x40.png"><input type="hidden" name="jan" value="youtube-40x40.png"> <a id="button-upload-jan" class="button">Обзор</a></td> 
        </tr>
```

Comment: картинка по этому адресу сама по себе открывается?

Comment: @Ипатьев, да, открывается

Comment: Доступ к сайту осуществляется по какому протоколу? http или https? В консоли хрома ошибки есть?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, протокол http, сайт у меня на локалке, в консоли ошибок нет, но когда я меняю везде директорию "download" на "image", то изображение отображается(так как я перенес его вручную в эту папку), но при загрузке нового изображения в консоли появляется ошибка VM5571:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (anonymous function) @ ajaxupload.js:610
Вот эта строка: 609if (response) {
                           610 response = eval("(" + response + ")");
                       611 } else {
                            612response = {};
                      613  }

Comment: Что это за `response`? Откуда оно берется? Чему равно? Вы уверены, что если в адресную строку браузера вбить `http://localhost/ocstore/download/youtube-40x40.png` то Вы увидите картинку?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov , если конкретно этот, то открывается страница приветствия опенсервера , а если полный путь начиная с file:///... то открывается

Comment: Значит файл по заданному адресу недоступен. Почему - смотрите сами. Может, каталога нет. Может public каталог у Вас другой. Может нет у сервера прав на чтение каталога или файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за ответы, так получилось что я сам додумался в чем проблема, а проблема была в файле .htaccess , после того как закомментил строку

```
  RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
```

все заработало)))

Comment: С какой стати ты тогда заявлял, что картинка по прямому пути открывается нормально? Тебе говорили в детстве что врать не хорошо?

Comment: @Ипатьев, Я уже писал что подумал не о том пути.